# tensorflow Dataset.from_generator using an generator that yield tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to convert some code into the new dataset API so that I can use the distribution strategy. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
def dataset_generator():
    while True:
        features, labels = ex_lib.get_image_batch(), ex_lib.get_feature_batch()
        yield features, labels

def get_ssf_input_fn():
    def input_fn():
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(dataset_generator,
                                              (tf.float32, tf.float32), ([None, config.image_height, config.image_width, config.image_channels], [None, 256]))

    return input_fn
```

the problem is `ex_lib.get_image_batch` and `ex_lib.get_feature_batch` gives me a tensor instead of a numpy array, and I cannot change the code in ex_lib. Also I cannot convert the tensor to numpy array here since I have no access to the `sess` here. With this code, it will throw

`` `generator` yielded an element that could not be converted to the expected type. The expected type was float32, but the yielded element was Tensor("GetImageBatch:0", dtype=uint8) ``

Is there a way to let my input_fn return a Dataset instead?

Comment: Bump. Facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to work around this problem with the following trick. Its efficiency is OK.

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(0).repeat().map(lambda _: dataset_generator())
```